# apk installer name

Tags: android, android-studio, package, apk, appinstaller

Is there a way to get apk installer name?
For example I downloaded a game and Installed from an another app (like an apk installer) can I get the package name or name of the installer?

Note: I know this code `packageManager.getInstallerPackageName(getPackageName());`  and it gives me com.google.android.packageinstaller but I don't want this. I mean I want like "app installed from com.myapp"